# PHP Immutable Object Efficiencies

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been working on an *immutable* object for use in PHP.  One can do this by adapting a singleton pattern and playing around with the magic methods easily enough, but I have a couple of specific needs here.

**1. Under no circumstances is a *reference* to a contained value to be returned.**

**2. If the contained data is an array (most likely a big 'ol tree loaded form `json_decode()`), then one must be able to search for a key using a search string**

e.g.:

```
  $thing = $foo->get( 'go.get.the.thingy.at.this.level' );
```

...which  would return:

```
   $foo->_data['go']['get']['the']['thingy']['at']['this']['level']
```

**3. When walking down a contained array looking for keys, references are used -- and *not* copies.**

- **This means that I will want to avoid the use of a `foreach()` call if it at all possible.**  If you don't understand what I mean (or understand why this is a concern), in PHP:

  - `foreach()` **does not** work on the object you are iterating.
  - `foreach()` **works on a *copy* of the object being iterated.**

## My Question

I've got something of a shell here (minor syntax problems aside), but I'd like to see if this can be made any more efficient, or if there are better tricks at accomplishing the same task

```
class   ProperlyProtectedObject {

    // PUBLIC STUFF

    /// Initializes the singelton and returns a reference -- or cowardly returns a null.
    public  static  function    init( $value )  {
        if( true === empty( self::$_self ) )    {   // empty returns true if 0, false, null, or not set
            if( false === isset( $value ) )  {      // isset returns true if not set or null.
                return  null;   // ...you idjit!
            }
            self::$_data    = new ProperlyProtectedObject( $value );
        }
        return  & self::$_self;
    }

    /// invoke ( php > =5.3 ): default
    public function __invoke( $var )    {
        return $this->get( $var );
    }

    public function     __call( $f, $args ) {
        return $this->get( $args );
    }

    public function  __callStatic( $f, $args ) {
        return null;  // idjit.
    }  

    /// get: NEAT TRICK:
    /// if you know that you are storing an array here, then you can pass a dot syntax
    /// string (e.g.: foo.bar.soemthing_else.foo.0 ) and 
    /// -- provided that your keys don't contain dots (:-P) --you can get the value of a
    /// nested array key!
    /// \return <Mixed> Any value **except** NULL is the value at the depth you are looking for.
    /// \return NULL    this means that   you.have.a.BAD.Key.string.SomeWhere 
    public function get( $val )   {
        $copyOfThing = null;

        if( true === is_array( self::$_data ) ) {
            if( true === is_string( $val ) )    {
                $keys   = explode( '.', $val );
                if( 0 < count( $keys ) {
                    $copyOfThing    = walk( self::$_data, $keys );
                }
            }
        }
        else    {
            $copyOfThing    = self::$_data;
        }

        return  $copyOfThing;
    }


    /// set: DOES NOTHING. This object is meant to take an act of congress to delete data.
    public function __set( $objProp, $value )   {
        // do nothing.
        // echo '<pre>DIE IN A FIRE!!!! ' . var_export( $objProp, true ) . '</pre>';
    }

    /// isset: 
    public function __isset( $objProp ) {
        return  ( null !== $this->get( $objProp ) ) ? true  : false;
    }

    /// unset: DOES NOTHING.This object is meant to take an act of congress to delete data
    public function __unset( $objProp ) {
        // do nothing.
        // echo '<pre>DIE IN A FIRE!!!! ' . var_export( $objProp, true ) . '</pre>';
    }


    // 
    // PRIVATE STUFF
    // 
    private $_self;             ///< the singleton instance
    private $_data  = Array();  ///< this is the data.  Just the data, and only the data.

    ///  CTOR: Singleton!
    private function     __construct( $value )  {
        self::$_data    = $value;            
    }

    /// CCTOR: Singletons have have no need to copy themselves
    private function     __clone()   {
        // do nothing
    }

    /// fetches the value from WAAAY down in the array
    private function    walk( Array &$arr, Array $keystack )   {
        $key    = array_pop( $keystack );
        if( false === array_key_exists( $key, $arr ) )   {
            return  null;
        }
        if( 0 count( $keystack ) )  {
            return  $arr[$key];
        }
        else    {
            return  walk( $arr[$key], $keystack );
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: "foreach() works on a copy of the object being iterated." --- that's not true http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html

Comment: "1. Under no circumstances is a reference to a contained value to be returned." --- what is the reason for that? Immutability is great because you have a single instance and pass it everywhere, instead of making copies. Immutability is about inability of modifying the object's state, not about creating another copy of the same data on every access.

Comment: Point taken on the ref count.  That's interesting.

Comment: Regarding returning a reference of the contained data, that shouldnt be allowed.
    ...getting a reference to the object that contains the data -- that's fine.  That's what a Singleton is.  Thus, an immutable singleton.